# How to enable custom system configuration in Magento 2.3.*?

Tags: magento, module, configuration, magento2, system.xml

I am currently working on a Magento project where I have to add a custom system configuration to manage my hosts.

I followed an old configuration I have used in an old project which uses the Magento version 2.2.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="catalog" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="config" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Setup</label>
                <field id="host" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="67" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Host</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

But starting from Magento 2.3 this solution doesn't work anymore.

Do I have to enable the configuration manually in order to see it in the admin configuration panel?

Comment: try setting `showInStore="0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your snippet and it works fine with me.

[image: Magento 2 Store Config]

Maybe there is a confusion between the `Catalog Tab` (blue underline), and the 'Catalog Section' (yellow highlight) ?

Tell me if so, i'll give you the snippet that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the section, you are missing the following nodes:

```
<section ...>
    <tab>$TAB</tab>
    <label>$LABEL</label>
    <resource>$RESOURCE</resource>
</section>
```